# Использование SherlockActionBar

Tags: android, java

Привет! Использую библиотеку для просмотра pdf файлов.Также подключена библиотека SherlockActionBar. Пытаюсь добавить титульник приложения, но приложение вылетает. Использование ActionBar обязательно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import net.sf.andpdf.pdfviewer.PdfViewerActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PDFView extends PdfViewerActivity   {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SherlockFragmentActivity mc = new SherlockFragmentActivity();
    mc.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.hello);
 }
public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;
}

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}

}
```

Comment: лог бы не помешал, но посмотри лучше как правильно юзают эту пдф либу

Comment: в том то и дело, что pdf показывает. А мне нужно добавить ActionBar, но не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в строках:

```
SherlockFragmentActivity mc = new SherlockFragmentActivity();
mc.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.hello);
```

В которых, скорее всего. возникает NPE на вызове *setTitle*, что, в общем-то, вполне логично и ожидаемо.

Отнаследуйте *PDFView* от *SherlockFragmentActivity*, либо же *PdfViewerActivity* должен наследоваться от него. После чего, в этой activity вы сможете сделать желаемое следующим образом:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.hello);
```

Кстати, статичный заголовок action bar'а разумнее будет указать в атрибуте *android:label* соответствующего тега *<activity>* в *AndroidManifest.xml*, нежели устанавливать его программно.

Answer (score 0):

`PdfViewerActivity - activity`, которое находится в библиотеке `android-pdf-viewer-library`.
Если перенаследовать `PDFView` от `SherlockFragmentActivity`, то `pdf` показываться не будет.

Comment: Ну тогда, стало быть, отнаследуйте PdfViewerActivity от SherlockFragmentActivity.

Comment: так они же в разных библиотеках находятся. Получается, что нужно к библиотеке подключить библиотеку, чтобы можно было бы наследовать PdfViewerActivity от SherlockFragmentActivity так чтоли?

Comment: Да. Иного способа использовать ABS, кроме как наследоваться от SherlockFragmentActivity, нет, увы.